# Change the output format of \cref from table to Table and from eq. to Equation

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

if you use \cref then you get references as eq. (1) / table (1) / fig. (1)

but I want it to produce Equation 1 / Table 1 / Figure 1

how to I set this?

I also want to know if it is possible to use cleveref without hyperref ... or change the link boxes to elegant underlines ...

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{book}
%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\title{hfvj}
\author{fgikf}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2 \label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\scriptsize\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Cube  & CUBEMEMBER & Returns a member or tuple in a cube hierarchy \\
Cube  & CUBEVALUE & Returns an aggregated value from a cube \\
Cube  & CUBESET & Defines a calculated set of members or tuples by sending a set     expression to the cube on the server \\
Cube  & CUBERANKEDMEMBER & Returns the nth, or ranked, member in a set \\
Cube  & CUBEKPIMEMBER & Returns a key performance indicator name, property, and measure, and displays the name and property in the cell. \\
Cube  & CUBEMEMBERPROPERTY & Returns the value of a member property in the cube \\
Cube  & CUBESETCOUNT & Returns the number of items in a set \\
Database & DAVERAGE & Averages the values in a column of a list or database that match conditions you specify \\
\end{tabular}%

\caption{rsghs}\label{esrg}
\end{table} 

\cref{esrg}

\cref{eq1}


\end{document}
```

[image: \cref format]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think there are four separate aspects to your posting. Three of the four objectives you've stated may be achieved by choosing the appropriate options when loading `cleveref`.

- To produce full rather than abbreviated names of cross-referenced items, you could load the cleveref package with the option `noabbrev`:

  ```
  \usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
  ```

  See also section 6.3 of the user guide of the `cleveref` package.
- If you want all names of cross-referenced items to start with an uppercase letter, be sure to specify the option `capitalize` (`capitalise` works too) as well :

  ```
  \usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}
  ```

  See also section 6.1 of the user guide of the `cleveref` package.
- One can certainly use `cleveref` without the `hyperref` package. (Note that the appearance of hypertargets is governed by options passed to `hyperref`, regardless of whether or not `cleveref` is loaded. Load the `hyperref` package with the option `colorlinks=true` if you don't want color rectangles around the target but, rather, the hypertarget itself to be rendered in color.) Back to `cleveref`: be sure to load it *after* `hyperref`. And, if you want `\cref` to make both the name and the number of the cross-referenced object into a hypertarget, just spefify the option `nameinlink` when laoding `cleveref`:

  ```
  \usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
  ```

  See also section 6.2 of the user guide of the `cleveref` package.
- If you want to suppress the automatic insertion of round parentheses around cross-reference equation numbers, i.e., if you prefer `Equation 1` over `Equation (1)`, you would need to add the following instruction to the preamble:

  ```
  \creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{#1}#3}
  ```

  The default setting is `\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(#1)}#3}` -- note the parentheses around `#1` in the argument of `\textup`.  Incidentally, you shoudn't be getting parentheses placed around the numbers of figures and tables, unless you've executed some code you haven't given us any information about so far.

Comment: is there an option to change the color of the links? right now they are coming as light green.

Comment: @ankhi - Your follow-up question is really about `hyperref` rather than about `cleveref`. If you want to change the color of all link types to, say, blue, you could do so by specifying the option `allcolors=blue`. Please study the `hyperref` manual for the full details; there are lots and lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

You can define those terms by yourself:

```
\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
\Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}
\crefname{table}{table}{tables}
\Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}

\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
```

To get Table 1 etc, you have to use `\Cref` instead of `\cref`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{book}
%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
\Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}
\crefname{table}{table}{tables}
\Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}

\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}

\title{hfvj}
\author{fgikf}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2 \label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\scriptsize\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llX}
Cube  & CUBEMEMBER & Returns a member or tuple in a cube hierarchy \\
Cube  & CUBEVALUE & Returns an aggregated value from a cube \\
Cube  & CUBESET & Defines a calculated set of members or tuples by sending a set     expression to the cube on the server \\
Cube  & CUBERANKEDMEMBER & Returns the nth, or ranked, member in a set \\
Cube  & CUBEKPIMEMBER & Returns a key performance indicator name, property, and measure, and displays the name and property in the cell. \\
Cube  & CUBEMEMBERPROPERTY & Returns the value of a member property in the cube \\
Cube  & CUBESETCOUNT & Returns the number of items in a set \\
Database & DAVERAGE & Averages the values in a column of a list or database that match conditions you specify \\
\end{tabularx}%

\caption{rsghs}\label{esrg}
\end{table}

\cref{esrg} \Cref{esrg}

\cref{eq1} \Cref{eq1}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also changed `tabular` to `tabularx` and made third column `X` type so that text wraps there.

Comment: While it's certainly possible to change the output of `\cref` by executing some low-level commands, I think it's far more convenient to do so by passing options to the `cleveref` package.